# Creating column based off values in separate row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assign

Here is an example of my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Arsenal FC', '', ''],
                   ['In', 'Age', 'Nat.'],
                   ['Leandro Trossard', 28, 'Belgium'],
                   ['Jakub Kiwior', 22, 'Poland'],
                   ['Jorginho', 32, 'Italy'],
                   ['Chelsea FC', '', ''],
                   ['In', 'Age', 'Nat.'],
                   ['Enzo Fernández ', 22, 'Argentina'],
                   ['Mykhaylo Mudryk', 22, 'Ukraine'],
                  ], columns=['Player', 'Age', 'Nat.'])
```

I want to create a new column `"Club"` which takes the string value of the cell in the `"Player"` and attaches it to the player below.

The tricky part is getting the right `clubs` assigned to the right `players`

This is my desired output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['In', 'Age', 'Nat.'],
                   ['Leandro Trossard', 28, 'Belgium', 'Arsenal FC'],
                   ['Jakub Kiwior', 22, 'Poland', 'Arsenal FC'],
                   ['Jorginho', 32, 'Italy', 'Arsenal FC'],
                   ['In', 'Age', 'Nat.'],
                   ['Enzo Fernández ', 22, 'Argentina', 'Chelsea FC'],
                   ['Mykhaylo Mudryk', 22, 'Ukraine', 'Chelsea FC'],
                  ], columns=['Player', 'Age', 'Nat.', 'Club'])
```

I can't find another question that relates to this problem. Is this possible in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option using boolean masks with [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
# which rows are empty string on Age?
m1 = df['Age'].ne('')
# which row are not internal headers?
m2 = df['Player'].ne('Player')

out = df[m1&m2].assign(Club=df.loc[m2, 'Player'].mask(m1).ffill())
```

Output:

```
             Player Age       Nat.        Club
2  Leandro Trossard  28    Belgium  Arsenal FC
3      Jakub Kiwior  22     Poland  Arsenal FC
4          Jorginho  32      Italy  Arsenal FC
7   Enzo Fernández   22  Argentina  Chelsea FC
8   Mykhaylo Mudryk  22    Ukraine  Chelsea FC
```

Intermediates:

```
             Player     m1        mask       ffill
0        Arsenal FC  False  Arsenal FC  Arsenal FC
2  Leandro Trossard   True         NaN  Arsenal FC
3      Jakub Kiwior   True         NaN  Arsenal FC
4          Jorginho   True         NaN  Arsenal FC
5        Chelsea FC  False  Chelsea FC  Chelsea FC
7   Enzo Fernández    True         NaN  Chelsea FC
8   Mykhaylo Mudryk   True         NaN  Chelsea FC
```

##### keeping the In/Age/Nat rows

```
# which rows are empty string on Age?
m1 = df['Age'].ne('')
# which row are not internal headers?
m2 = df['Player'].ne('In')

out = df[m1].assign(Club=df.loc[m2, 'Player'].mask(m1).ffill())
```

Output:

```
             Player  Age       Nat.        Club
1                In  Age       Nat.         NaN
2  Leandro Trossard   28    Belgium  Arsenal FC
3      Jakub Kiwior   22     Poland  Arsenal FC
4          Jorginho   32      Italy  Arsenal FC
6                In  Age       Nat.         NaN
7   Enzo Fernández    22  Argentina  Chelsea FC
8   Mykhaylo Mudryk   22    Ukraine  Chelsea FC
```

Comment: Hi @mozway ! This isn't working for me right now, but I've edited the question to reflect my actual dataframe.

Comment: @code_machine you can probably guess by yourself that you now need to use `m2 = df['Player'].ne('In')`, similarly if you have NaN in place of empty strings you can replace `ne('')` with `notna()` ;)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to use this method without removing the `['In', 'Age', 'Nat.']` columns?

Comment: Hi @mozway , is it possible to achieve what I mentioned in the comment above? 6c00h 's method works well but would involve creating a list of 60+ club names

Comment: @code_machine yes of course, you just need to remove `&m2`, see update

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Arsenal FC', '', ''],
                   ['In', 'Age', 'Nat.'],
                   ['Leandro Trossard', 28, 'Belgium'],
                   ['Jakub Kiwior', 22, 'Poland'],
                   ['Jorginho', 32, 'Italy'],
                   ['Chelsea FC', '', ''],
                   ['In', 'Age', 'Nat.'],
                   ['Enzo Fernández ', 22, 'Argentina'],
                   ['Mykhaylo Mudryk', 22, 'Ukraine'],
                  ], columns=['Player', 'Age', 'Nat.'])

clubs = []
current_club = None
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Player'] in ['Arsenal FC', 'Chelsea FC']:
        current_club = row['Player']
    elif row['Player'] == 'In':
        continue
    else:
        clubs.append(current_club)

df['Club'] = clubs

print(df)
```

Output:

```
           Player Age     Nat.       Club
0      Arsenal FC        Arsenal FC
1             In   Age     Nat.      NaN
2  Leandro Trossard  28   Belgium  Arsenal FC
3     Jakub Kiwior  22   Poland  Arsenal FC
4         Jorginho  32    Italy  Arsenal FC
5       Chelsea FC        Chelsea FC
6             In   Age     Nat.      NaN
7  Enzo Fernández   22 Argentina  Chelsea FC
8  Mykhaylo Mudryk  22   Ukraine  Chelsea FC
```

Edit 2: Multiple club names

```
clubs = ['Arsenal FC', 'Chelsea FC', 'Other Club 1', 'Other Club 2', ..., 'Other Club n']

def get_club(row, clubs):
    if row['Player'] in clubs:
        return row['Player']
    else:
        return ''

df['Club'] = ''
club = ''
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Player'] in clubs:
        club = row['Player']
    else:
        df.at[index, 'Club'] = club

df = df[df['Club'] != ''].reset_index(drop=True)
df['Club'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_club(x, clubs), axis=1)
```

Comment: Hi there! Is it possible to use this method without removing the `['In', 'Age', 'Nat.']` columns?

Comment: Great thanks. Is there another way to implement this code when there are multiple club names (60+) other than "Arsenal FC" and "Chelsea FC" ?

Comment: You can extend the code to handle multiple club names by creating a list of all the club names and checking the Player column against that list